# Gradle dependency not working in android studio

Tags: android, dependencies, gradle

I am migrating to work with android studio and can't seem to be able to add external libraries with Gradle build.

To start, i'm trying to add the support library and use the ViewPager.

I started a new project and added the support library to my dependencies like it says in the android studio page, this is my gradle.build file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
    compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'
}
```

When I try to use the ViewPager class in my MainActivity.java, it doesn't find the library or asks me to import it.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you try to 'clean' and rebuild your project?

Comment: but if i try to add another dependency like pagerslidingtabstrip it wont work... :\

Comment: Great! I didnt want to put it as an answer but i can i you want :P

Comment: also now it wont recognize R.layout ....

Comment: Make sure you assemble it fully. I forget what's it called.

Comment: hmm... just pressed a bunch of times on make, compile and rebuild ind it sorted itself... weird :/

Comment: I had to do all of the above and then close and reopen Android Studio (Hedgehog). Something's definitely not right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll add my answer from the comments since it might help someone else:
Try to 'clean' and rebuild your project, if it still acting up, try to make and compile the project.

Comment: My problem was that gradle was in offline mode and I didn't notice it. when I was syncing, cleaning or rebuilding, it didn't tell me that gradle is in offline mode, but only in building it showed me an error. Thanks.